# PHP web Crawler, check for text and save it on external txt

Tags: php, web-crawler

I'm looking to build a fetcher in PHP/JS that basically do these tasks:

**Connect to a URL with a dictionary variable inside it**

Es www.domain.com/#word1 , www.domain.com/#word2 , www.domain.com/#word3

Where the words are picked up in an external .txt file

**Fetch the html page content**

```
function check_url($url) {
$page = file_get_contents($url);
```

**Check for some text**

```
$text= '<p>some text</p>';
if (strpos($page, $text) === FALSE)
```

**Append words with coincidences in an external file txt**

```
{
$fp = fopen('coincidenceswords.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $text);
fclose($fp);
    } else {
        echo "Naughty webpage!";
    }
```

***Problems***

I am pretty n00bs in php, still learning, and i have doubts with some points:

How to generate a different $url based on an external dictionary txt file, as described in point 1?

How make this a cycle? Crawler generate the url sequentially using words in the dictionary.txt file, download the page, check for occurrence, if find it save the word in the coincidenceswords.txt, and then repeat the cycle with next generated url.

*It might sound trivial to the most experienced, but I'm trying to solve it without great results, any help is really appreciated*

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: You'd need a separator of some kind between the URLs in the txt doc (comma, pipe, string of 12 x @, SOMETHING that wouldn't be in the URL) to explode, then use a foreach loop to go through each URL from the exploded array. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php and http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I think that you may have to know about [tag:xpath] and save xpath required for each website to easily allow access contents on the remote page.